# Where locate my Json files in AngularJs App using $translate service

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm trying to integrate the service Translate of angularJs in my app. I proceed as the following :

I added in my app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [pascalprecht.translate' ]);

myApp.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {

      $translateProvider
      .useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: '/translations/locale-',
        suffix: '.json'
      })
      .preferredLanguage('en')
      .useMissingTranslationHandlerLog()
    }]);
```

I placed my json:

[image: place of json files]

I got the error that the file local-en.json doesn'ot exist?

Comment: Have you tried with a relative path? (i.e. ./translations or something like that?

Comment: it works thx !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your prefix is `/translations/locale-`. This causes the translate service to look for the files in the root folder of the server. Change it to `./translations/locale-` and it looks for the files in the current folder.